Faster simulation of two spins
I am working on a code to simulate two spins under a certain condition. I have tried to optimize the code as much as I can, however this code is not so fast yet, taking long time to evaluate, but I want it to run faster, as I want to check the data while varying parameters.
Following is my code:
ρ0 = {{0, 0, 1/2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1/2}, {1/2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/2, 0, 0}};
spinint = {{1/4, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -(1/4), 0, 0}, {0, 0, -(1/4), 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1/4}};
operator = {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}};

ωD = 2 2 π 0.5; 
ωr = 2 2 π 10; 
τr = (2 π)/ωr;
ωDt = ωD (√2 Sin[2 β] Cos[ωr t + γ] - (Sin[β])^2 Cos[2 ωr t + 2 γ]);

Dipol1t[β_, γ_] = N@Integrate[ωDt, {t, 0, τr/2}];
Selectedangle = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 0, π, π/100}, {j, 0, 2 π, π/100}], 1];
NBlock = Range[0, 128];

propagator[β_, γ_, N_] := MatrixExp[-2 N I Dipol1t[β, γ] (2 spinint)];
ρs[β_, γ_, N_] := Dot[propagator[β, γ, N], ρ0, 
 propagator[β, γ, N]\[ConjugateTranspose]];
output1[β_, γ_, N_] := Tr[(operator)\[ConjugateTranspose] . #] & /@ ρs[β, γ, N];
output2[N_] := Total[ParallelMap[output1[#[[1]], #[[2]], N] &, Selectedangle]];

finaloutput = ParallelTable[
 output2[NBlock[[i]]], {i, 1, Length@NBlock}]; // AbsoluteTiming

Are there any techniques for fast computation or simplifying things that I don't know?

When I run your code I get messages ParallelMap::subpar: Parallel computations cannot be nested; proceeding with sequential evaluation.

@Jagra yes, that error message appears while running with "ParallelMap", but at the end it evaluates with result. I also have tried with "Map" but it takes even more longer to evaluate. I am using Mathematica 12.0

If you change all of those SetDelayed's (:=) in the definitions to Set's (=), it runs really fast. You are forcing Mathematica to re-evaluate each of these operations every time they are called, but since they can be computed symbolically pretty quickly, just defining them (propagator, output1, etc.) using = instead of := will make it so that they are only computed once.

Also, don't use N as a variable name; that's a built-in function in Mathtematica, and that might cause issues. Use something like nn instead.

Everything, up to your last expression can be solved analytically.
\[Rho]0={{0,0,1/2,0},{0,0,0,1/2},{1/2,0,0,0},{0,1/2,0,0}};
spinint={{1/4,0,0,0},{0,-(1/4),0,0},{0,0,-(1/4),0},{0,0,0,1/4}};
operator={{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0}};

\[Omega]D=2 2 \[Pi] 1/2;
\[Omega]r=2 2 \[Pi] 10;
\[Tau]r=(2 \[Pi])/\[Omega]r;
\[Omega]Dt=\[Omega]D (\[Sqrt]2 Sin[2 \[Beta]] Cos[\[Omega]r t+\[Gamma]]-(Sin[\[Beta]])^2 Cos[2 \[Omega]r t+2 \[Gamma]]);

Dipol1t=Integrate[\[Omega]Dt,{t,0,\[Tau]r/2}];

propagator=MatrixExp[-2 n*I Dipol1t (2 spinint)];
\[Rho]s=Dot[propagator,\[Rho]0,propagator\[ConjugateTranspose]];
output1=Tr[(operator)\[ConjugateTranspose].#]&/@\[Rho]s;

(*this makes sense so that we get rid of those Conjugates, Re and Im*)
output1S=FullSimplify[output1,n>=0&&2Pi>=\[Beta]>=0&&2Pi>=\[Gamma]>=0]


{
1/2 E^(2/5 I Sqrt[2] n Cos[[Beta]] Sin[[Beta]] Sin[[Gamma]]),
1/2 E^(-(2/5) I Sqrt[2] n Cos[[Beta]] Sin[[Beta]] Sin[[Gamma]]),
0,
0
}

Following it up with your summation:
NBlock = Range[0, 128];
output2Sum=N@Sum[output1S,{\[Beta],0,Pi,Pi/100},{\[Gamma],0,2Pi,Pi/100}];
finaloutput=Table[N[output2Sum]/.n->NBlock[[i]],{i,1,Length@NBlock}];//AbsoluteTiming

Finishes within 0.8s on my machine. (Two seconds including the summation) And is within 10-10 of your result. So should be fine.
